# SQL injections in Rails 4 issue

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection

I'm trying to learn about SQL injections and have tried to implement these, but when I put this code in my controller:

```
params[:username] = "johndoe') OR admin = 't' --"
@user_query = User.find(:first, :conditions => "username = '#{params[:username]}'")
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (first, {:conditions=>"username = 'johndoe') OR admin = 't' --'"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

I have created a User Model with the username "johndoe", but I am still getting no proper response. BTW I am using Rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an ancient Rails syntax. Don't use

```
find(:first, :condition => <condition>) ...
```

Instead use

```
User.where(<condtion>).first
```

`find` accepts a list of IDs to lookup records for. You're giving it an ID of `:first` and an ID of `condition: ...`, which aren't going to match any records.

Comment: Okay thanks, it seemed that all the sql tutorials used the find method, but now i'll use where instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.where(attr1: value, attr2: value2)
```

or for single items

```
User.find_by(attr1: value, attr2: value)
```

Bear in mind that while doing all this, it would be valuable to check what the actual sql statement is by adding "to_sql" to the end of the query method (From what I remember, find_by just does a LIMIT by 1)